# How to use ReportItem property(ReportItems!TextboxName.Value) in body of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012

I'm working on SSRS Report using report builder and want to get a value of a textbox of table using (ReportItems!textboxName.Value). Can I do this? After searching on internet i found that i Cant use it in report's body(may be i'm wrong) than how I can get the value of specific textbox of table?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: please see this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058401/can-we-get-value-of-above-cell-of-same-column-of-table-in-ssrs-report-builder-h/30067666#30067666 
i have posted my detailed problem there. if you understand then let me know i'll explain you

Comment: This question appears to lack basic research, i.e. trying it before asking. You should've tested your own question, instead of just asking others whether it would work. What you can't do with a `ReportItem` in the body is to aggregate it; that can only be done in a page header or footer. (This is a stupid restriction, which I hate.) However, simply getting a single value should work fine. Again, just try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that should be valid, here is a link to the specific [technet article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285(v=sql.110).aspx) on the topic.

The basic format is something along the lines of:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox2.Value
```

There are a couple of restrictions on it because of when it would be generated, but it shouldn't have a problem being in the body.